# Find record where subject code is not zero for that class

Tags: sql

This is student table.

```
StudentId ClassId SubjectCode
101       201     0
101       201     1
101       301     1
101       401     0
```

Suppose I making final marksheet for his/her course.Student can attend different class.I want to find out the row where
student does not have subjectcode 0 for that class.Like this

```
   101       301     1
```

How to do that?
If I do like this

```
select Studentid,classId,subjectcode from Student
where operator <> 0
```

That give this record also

```
101 201 1    .I don't want that.because it has 0 for that class 201.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `GROUP BY` and `HAVING`:

```
SELECT 
    StudentId, ClassId
FROM Student
GROUP BY
    StudentId, ClassId
HAVING
    SUM(CASE WHEN SubjectCode = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0
```

<kbd>[**ONLINE DEMO**](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/479272)</kbd>